# How to convert long or double int datatype to String inFfirebase dataSnapshot

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have create realtime quiz application using with Firebase database but when I retrieve integer value from database it show me error.

```
com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Failed to convert value of type java.lang.Long to String
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzepg.zzb(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzepg.zza(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot.getValue(Unknown Source)
    at com.ejobbox.ejobbox.SimpleQuiz$6.onDataChange(SimpleQuiz.java:164)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzejp.zza(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzelk.zza(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzelq.run(Unknown Source)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:742)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5523)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:739)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:629)
```

**at com.ejobbox.ejobbox.SimpleQuiz$6.onDataChange(SimpleQuiz.java:164)**

```
 DatabaseReference mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        DatabaseReference gOption1=mDatabase.child(mQuestionNumber+"/choice1");
        gOption1.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                String Option1=String.valueOf(dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class).toString());
                mButtonChoice1.setText(Option1);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
```

in this application i can't define particular data type because datatype datatype field value will be string or integer want to convert it when after data retrieve so please let me know how can i do this.

**i have use String.valueOf() for convert data but it not work so please help me how can i convert data into string.**

```
String Option1=String.valueOf(dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class).toString());
```

**SimpleQuiz.Java**

```
package com.ejobbox.ejobbox;

import android.graphics.Color;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

public class SimpleQuiz extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TextView mScoreView;
    private TextView mQuestionView;
    private Button mButtonChoice1;
    private Button mButtonChoice2;
    private Button mButtonChoice3;
    private Button mButtonChoice4;

    private String mAnswer;
    private int mScore = 0;
    private int mQuestionNumber = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.simple_quiz);
        mScoreView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.score);
        mQuestionView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.question);
        mButtonChoice1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.choice1);
        mButtonChoice2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.choice2);
        mButtonChoice3 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.choice3);
        mButtonChoice4 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.choice4);

        updateQuestion();

        //Start of Button Listener for Button1
        mButtonChoice1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view){
                //My logic for Button goes in here

                if (mButtonChoice1.getText().equals(mAnswer)){
                    mScore = mScore + 1;
                    updateScore(mScore);
                    updateQuestion();
                    //This line of code is optiona
                    Toast.makeText(SimpleQuiz.this, "correct", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    mButtonChoice1.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#29b200"));
                }else {
                    mButtonChoice1.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#c10000"));
                    Toast.makeText(SimpleQuiz.this, "wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    updateQuestion();
                }
            }
        });

        //End of Button Listener for Button1

        //Start of Button Listener for Button2
        mButtonChoice2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view){
                //My logic for Button goes in here

                if (mButtonChoice2.getText().equals(mAnswer)){
                    mScore = mScore + 1;
                    updateScore(mScore);
                    updateQuestion();
                    //This line of code is optiona
                    mButtonChoice2.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#29b200"));
                    Toast.makeText(SimpleQuiz.this, "correct", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }else {
                    mButtonChoice2.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#c10000"));
                    Toast.makeText(SimpleQuiz.this, "wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    updateQuestion();
                }
            }
        });

        //End of Button Listener for Button2
        //Start of Button Listener for Button3
        mButtonChoice3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view){
                //My logic for Button goes in here

                if (mButtonChoice3.getText().equals(mAnswer)){
                    mScore = mScore + 1;
                    updateScore(mScore);
                    updateQuestion();
                    //This line of code is optiona
                    mButtonChoice3.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#29b200"));
                    Toast.makeText(SimpleQuiz.this, "correct", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }else {
                    mButtonChoice3.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#c10000"));
                    Toast.makeText(SimpleQuiz.this, "wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    updateQuestion();
                }
            }
        });
        //End of Button Listener for Button3
        mButtonChoice4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view){
                //My logic for Button goes in here

                if (mButtonChoice4.getText().equals(mAnswer)){
                    mScore = mScore + 1;
                    updateScore(mScore);
                    updateQuestion();
                    //This line of code is optiona
                    mButtonChoice4.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#29b200"));
                    Toast.makeText(SimpleQuiz.this, "correct", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }else {
                    mButtonChoice1.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#c10000"));
                    Toast.makeText(SimpleQuiz.this, "wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    updateQuestion();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void updateQuestion(){

        DatabaseReference mQuestion1 = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        DatabaseReference gQuestion1=mQuestion1.child(mQuestionNumber+"/question");
        gQuestion1.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                String question1=String.valueOf(dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class).toString());
                mQuestionView.setText(question1);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

        DatabaseReference mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        DatabaseReference gOption1=mDatabase.child(mQuestionNumber+"/choice1");
        gOption1.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                String Option1=String.valueOf(dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class).toString());
                mButtonChoice1.setText(Option1);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });


        DatabaseReference gOption2=mDatabase.child(mQuestionNumber+"/choice2");
        gOption2.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                String Option2=String.valueOf(dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class).toString());
                mButtonChoice2.setText(Option2);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });


        DatabaseReference gOption3=mDatabase.child(mQuestionNumber+"/choice3");
        gOption3.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                String Option3=String.valueOf(dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class).toString());
                mButtonChoice3.setText(Option3);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });


        DatabaseReference gOption4=mDatabase.child(mQuestionNumber+"/choice4");
        gOption4.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                String Option4=String.valueOf(dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class).toString());
                mButtonChoice4.setText(Option4);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

        DatabaseReference mQAnswer=mDatabase.child(mQuestionNumber+"/answer");
        mQAnswer.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                mAnswer=String.valueOf(dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class));
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
        mQuestionNumber++;
    }


    private void updateScore(int point) {
        mScoreView.setText("" + mScore);
    }
}
```

**Database Structure**

```
{
  "0" : {
    "answer" : "President",
    "choice1" : "PM",
    "choice2" : "AM",
    "choice3" : "President",
    "choice4" : "Vice President",
    "question" : "who is Ramnath kovind ?"
  },
  "1" : {
    "answer" : "Red",
    "choice1" : "Red",
    "choice2" : "Green",
    "choice3" : "Black",
    "choice4" : "Yellow",
    "question" : "Rose color is___?"
  },
  "2" : {
    "answer" : 3,
    "choice1" : 5,
    "choice2" : 4,
    "choice3" : 3,
    "choice4" : 2,
    "question" : "How many color in indian flage ?"
  },

  "UpdateVersion" : 1,
  "apkUrls" : "https://www.ejobbox.com"
}
```

Comment: You should not have multiple value types for a field. I think your best option is to save your long values as string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this, please change this line of code:

```
String Option1=String.valueOf(dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class).toString());
```

with

```
String Option1=String.valueOf(dataSnapshot.getValue(Long.class));
```

Remember, `dataSnapshot.getValue(Long.class)` returns a `long`, which is primitive and you cannot invoke `toString()` on the primitive type.

Because the `choice1` holds different types of objects, to solve the problem, the OP decided to have all values as Strings. So instead of using the following line of code:

```
ref.child("choice1").setValue(5);
```

We should use:

```
use ref.child("choice1").setValue("5");
```

Using `quotation marks`, the value will be stores as String. In the end, to make it work, just remove the testing data and add fresh data.

Comment: Seeing your database, I can tell your that contains wrong values. You need to have the values of your `choice1` property to be the same in each object. In the first object the value is `"PM"` which is a String, in the second object you have the value `"Red"` which is also a String and the third the value is `5`, which is a `Long`.

Comment: So in order to solve this, remove all that data add fresh data so you can have all the values within all objects of the same type. If all the value will be of type `Long`, then my solution will work. If you decide to be String, then just simply use: `String Option1=dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);` Ok? Tell me if it work.

Comment: it not work now it show me error "Failed to convert a value of type java.lang.String to long."

in quiz not specific data in all time some time add years and some time date so how can handle it. any globel data type that manage all type of data.
now how can i resolve it please help me.

Comment: Have you read what I have just written? First delete those items from your database, are wrong. You cannot solve this, having that data in your database. Then add fresh data. If all the values of `choice1` property will be of type **Long**, then **my solution will work**. If it will be **String**, then just simply use: `String Option1=dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);` Works?

Comment: in quiz not specific data in all time some time add years and some time date so how can handle it. any global data type that manage all type of data.

Comment: Then when you add data to the database, make the value of that property String. That's it! So don't use something like this: `ref.child("choice1").setValue(5)`, use `ref.child("choice1").setValue("5")`. See the quotation marks? This means that will be strings.

Comment: Should work for sure. Give it a try and tell me if it works.

Comment: @AlexMamo Is it possible you include some of the information from the comments in your answer? If i only read the question/answer and not the comments i would think this doesn't really answer the question.

Comment: @AndréKool Thanks. You're right. Just updated the answer. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Three approach are possible:

1st: Its a pretty simple method, but I wouldn't prefer it.

```
String option1 = dataSnapshot.getValue() + ""; //it it works
```

2nd: You need to check each and every data type for the data you are accessing and convert them accordingly.

```
if ((dataSnapshot.getValue()) instanceof Long )
{
    String Option1=String.valueOf(dataSnapshot.getValue(Long.class));
}
else if ((dataSnapshot.getValue()) instanceof Double )
{
    String Option1=String.valueOf(dataSnapshot.getValue(Double.class));
}
else if (...)
{
    //and so on
}
```

3rd: You can have every data in your database as string. How to do that? Just add any letter after every data. For example,

```
"choice1" : 5,
"choice2" : 4,
"choice3" : 3,
"choice4" : 2,
```

will become

```
"choice1" : 5L,
"choice2" : 4L,
"choice3" : 3L,
"choice4" : 2L,
```

In this way every data will be of type "String". Then use

```
String Option1 = String.valueOf(dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class));
int indexno = Option1.indexOf("L");
Option1 = Option1.substring(0,indexno); //this line will remove "L" from the string
```